# Is it possible to achieve two way data binding in angular without using ng-model and ng-bind?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

It is one of the question i was asked in an interview,i have basic knowledge of angularJs and i know it is possible to achieve two way data binding using ng-model and ng-bind in Angular.i want to know if there is another way to achieve the same.

Comment: Seems on odd question but directive `=` scope binding achieves two-way binding

Comment: Also, you probably meant `ng-model`, not `ng-modal`

Comment: *"i know it is possible to achive two way data binding using ng-modal and ng-bind in Angular"* <- if you know it's possible, why are you asking here?

Comment: @Phil Read question again and i am asking if it is possible to achieve it without ng-model and ng-bind

Answer (score 0):

- You can just use the interpolation operator `{{}}` which is *like* ng-bind but technically is *not*
- You can use the `=` binding in directives like @phil has said
- You can use `$scope.$watch`